# How can vacuum have an impedance?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrical-resistance, vacuum

Vacuum is said to have an intrinsic impedance. What is the source of this? Impedance is quite understandable in bulk matter, but I'm unable to comprehend it's presence in vacuum.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79364/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36448/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Impedance is a response of material to excitation. E.g., if we define an impedance of a conductor as a ratio of the applied bias to the resulting current,
$$Z(\omega) =\frac{V(\omega)}{I(\omega)},$$
then nothing prevents us from defining it in the same way for vacuum. Naturally one would expect this impedance to be something simple like 1 (electromagnetic field passes without attenuation) or 0 (no electric current).

Specifically, one talking about the impedance of free space one often talks about [the propagation of electromagnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_of_free_space)
$$Z = \frac{E}{H} = \sqrt{\frac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_0}},$$
which has dimensionality of resistance. The fact that in SI system of units this ratio is not $1$ is one of the main arguments against using this system of units in physics.

Comment: You seem to have posted this answer without having finished it.

Comment: vacuum impedance: $Z_0=\sqrt{\frac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_0}}=377\Omega$

Comment: @hyportnex thanks, I corrected the formula. However, I do not use the SI units: $\mu_0 = \epsilon_0 = 1$

Comment: your voltmeter must be calibrated in statvolts, how is your car battery?

Comment: Can you try to figure out how to do the maths mark-up? It would make it easier to read...

Comment: @OscarBravo what exactly the problem? If you want to edit something for better readibility - feel free to do so.

Comment: @hyportnex I suppose that engineers find SI units more convenient - I am a theoretical physicist.

Comment: @Vadim Do you see the mathjax correctly formatted? I see the mark-up... It's not just you, it's the whole site - that's weird...

Comment: @OscarBravo I have no idea what you are talking about.